# Multiple ng-controllers in index.html

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, controller

```
This is my app.js  And I want add details to two tables .But when I run the code it only adds details to a one table.
```

This is for adding details to table medi10.
    app.controller("inforCtrl", function($scope, $cordovaSQLite){

```
        $scope.add = function(user){

            var query1 = "INSERT INTO medi10(drug,reason,dname)VALUES(?,?,?)";
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query1,[user.drug,user.reason,user.dname])

      alert("added");

        }

    });
```

This is to add details to table reminder4.
     app .controller("appCtrl", function($scope, $cordovaSQLite){

```
        $scope.add = function(user){

            var query = "INSERT INTO reminder4(drug,time,how)VALUES(?,?,?)";
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query,[user.dg,user.re,user.mel])

      alert("added");

        }

    })
```

Comment: Hmmm I don't think its possible.

Comment: You can but in other DOM not in same DOM . `<div ng-controller="inforCtrl"></div>  ....<div ng-controller="appCtrl"></div>` and if bind multiple controller in same DOM just first of it bind. and its better use `controllerAs` syntax when use multiple controller in same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you **cannot** have, even if you have the first one will be considered as ng-controller.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl1', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Tom";
});
app.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Cruise";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
 </head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl1" ng-controller="myCtrl2">
     {{name}}
</body>
</html>
```

If you really want to have two ng-controllers across a page you can do by separating divs.

Comment: I have add some of my app.js codings in to the above post. I have two .controllers in my app.js . But when I run them the data is only adding to one table. How can I have these controllers in my app.js.

Comment: you cannot do that!

Comment: So  how can I  create the function to have data adding to two or multiple tables

Comment: In my app I need to let user to enter details and I  want to save them to tables. I can do this to  a page successfully using .controller in app.js But I want to add the same functionality to other pages too. How can I do that? without using multiple .controllers

Comment: use a service instead

Comment: Thanks ..I 've added a separate controller.js file and another js file to explain it. Now it is working fine.